# Manifolds realized as lagrangians of a Calabi-Yau?

Tags: complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Every smooth manifold $M$ can be realized as a Lagrangian submanifold of a symplectic manifold (for example, inside its own cotangent bundle $T^*M$ carrying the standard symplectic form $\omega_0$).

From this [question/answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26776/k%C3%A4hler-structure-on-cotangent-bundle) it looks as though every smooth (compact) manifold can be realized as a Lagrangian submanifold of a Kahler manifold by making a neighborhood of the zero section of the cotangent bundle Kahler.

What about realizing a smooth manifold as a Lagrangian submanifold of a Calabi-Yau manifold? I would guess this is more restrictive (for example, one probably can't always put a Calabi-Yau structure on a neighborhood in the cotangnet bundle), but is much known about this?

Comment: My answer may be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250108/what-exactly-is-the-kahler-class-of-a-torus/2651643#2651643